# How to capture the iteration number dyanmically inside test while using pytest-repeat

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I'm executing my selenium script multiple times by using pytest-repeat. i need to capture the iteration number during execution and make use of it.

I explored pytest.mark, pytest.collect & pytest.Collector

```
class Testone():

 @pytest.fixture()

 def setup(self):

 @pytest.mark.repeat(RowCount)

 def test_create_eq(self,setup):
```

Need to capture the iteration number here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be an easier and straightforward way than what I describe below. `pytest-repeat` has a fixture `__pytest_repeat_step_number` which I hoped could provide the current step number for the test but it did not.

`request.node.name` provides the name of the test function generated by `pytest_repeat` and it has the step number which can be extracted for your purpose.

```py
import pytest

class Testone():

    @pytest.fixture()
    def setup(self):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.repeat(4)
    def test_create_eq(self,setup,request):
        current_step = request.node.name.split('[')[1].split('-')[0]  #string form; parse to int, if required
```

Comment: Note that the assignment to `current_step` will fail if you omit `@pytest.mark.repeat` and instead pass the count using `--count <n>` option (but don't pass the option.)  Easily fixed, of course.  Very helpful post, thanks!